# What concept is used in .net for creating mobile software?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, mobile

I know in java we are using j2me for developing mobile software. What is the equivalent in .NET? What would be the best way to learn it? Can I also get book recommendations for a beginner?

Comment: Is your bid auction about to expire? Is that why you are editing so little each time?

Comment: You already got Jon Skeet to answer, what more do you want?

Comment: @ratty, your bogus edits (trying to make your questions bump unto the frontpage) are subject of a discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38655/how-to-deal-with-question-bumping/ Please play the game nicely! When not getting the answer you want then improve the question instead.

Answer (score 7):

The .NET Compact framework is what you're looking for. [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) / [MS Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx)

There are a few of the main concepts of mobile development with .NET outlined on [this page](http://www.devbuzz.com/Windows-Mobile-Compact-Framework.aspx) also.

This is of course assuming you're wishing to develop for Windows Mobile OS phones. There are other ways to develop for software such as the iPhone - you'd have to look into [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) for that.

There's an [excellent introduction video here](http://vimeo.com/9150434) if you're interested (Chris Hardy - C# on the iPhone with MonoTouch)

Comment: Looks like no future Microsoft phones will support the .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework).

Answer (score 1):

The [.Net Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx), but note that it [only runs on Windows devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms172550.aspx) (Windows Mobile, Windows CE, Windows Embedded).

Answer (score 1):

Be a bit careful here -- the answer to this question is probably about to change in a big way as Silverlight seems to be the new platform for third party mobile applications on Windows devices.  Though it is very overdue and it's not completely clear what is happening, I doubt whether now is a good time to start learning the Compact Framework.